# How to format date in android environment

Tags: android, android-layout, date-formatting, android-datepicker, android-date

I want to display date in month and date format(ex:May 26).But when I am trying to use it was showing cannot resolve method.

```
String dateStr = DateFormat.format("MMM dd", cal.getTime().getTime()).toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd", Locale.US);
Date date = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(cal.getTime().getTime());
String dateStr = sdf.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
    String date = format.format(Date.parse(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(0));  
   DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));  
   DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));
```

The above three lines will give:

```
Dec 31, 1969  
Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM  
4:00:00 PM  12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat.

```
String dat = "2017-01-29 09:49:22"
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dat);
String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                        Date convertedDate = format.parse(selectedDate);
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(convertedDate);
                        dateSelection.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%1$td %1$tB, %1$tY", cal));



output:  9 May, 2017
```